# How to display css on drupal local website

Tags: jquery, css, apache, ubuntu, drupal-8

I installed the cms Drupal 8 on my server(ubuntu 16) where is also installed apache2, phpmyadmin, php 7.All is ok, I could install drupal and I can access to the default site but there's no formatting as if the css couldn't be activated. I saw on some forum that you have to disable "aggregating css files" and "aggregating javascript files" by going to admin/config/development/performance. I tryed it but the css still doesn't display.

Comment: You should provide more details if you are planning to get some answers

Comment: what theme is currently enabled?

Comment: Is the drupal site correctly linking to the stylesheet? Can you inspect the code in the browser to see if the css file is referenced in the header?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I thought it was a technical problem but finally I only have to change theme. The theme by default was "stark 8.8.1". I change it and now it's ok!

Answer (score 0):

this is correct admin/config/development/performance. Just remove below checkboxes & save your config and after that clear/flush your cache.

BANDWIDTH OPTIMIZATION -

1) Aggregate CSS files
2) Aggregate JavaScript files

This will work for me.

Hope this will work.